# Perform an actionListener once and proceed to another actionListener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

Anyone have another view for this issue?

I need assistance for this part of the code, I would like to perform an actionListener (Add white border to the Jbutton pressed) only ONCE and proceed to another actionListener (Add blue border to another (different)Jbutton pressed). Here's my code which is only performing the white border continuously.
Your feedback is much appreciated.

```
for(int c = 0; c< 10; c++) 
        {
            for (int r = 0; r< 10; r++)
            {
                bu1[c][r] = new JButton(); //Insert Into List
                panel.add(bu1[c][r]);

                final int i = c;
                final int j = r;

                bu1[i][j].addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                    {
                        if  (e.getSource() == bu1[i][j])
                        {
                            bu1[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE, 2));
                            bu1[i][j].removeActionListener(this);
                        }

                    }    

            });

                bu1[i][j].addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                    {
                        if  (e.getSource() == bu1[i][j])
                        {
                            bu1[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 2));
                        }

                    }    

            });
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, then the simplest solution is to keep a `count` in your `ActionListener`. Because then you only need one `ActionListener` with something like,

```
private int count = 0;
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  JButton obj = bu1[i][j]; // <-- save the typing.
  if (e.getSource() == obj) {
    if (count == 0) { 
      obj.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(
          Color.WHITE, 2)); // <-- set to white on 0.
    } else if (count == 1) {
      obj.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(
          Color.BLUE, 2)); // <-- set to blue on 1.
    }
    count++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer....I am trying it out but I have problems to setBorder on objects.

Comment: @user3693592 Sorry. Edited.

Comment: No problem at all!!....but still it did not work. Could it be since I have inserted your code in the nested loop. I had to do that as I need "bu1[i][j".

Comment: Are you still removing the listener?

Comment: Can you try a debugger?

Comment: Maybe also try calling repaint.

Comment: Since it is looping the count is being reset to 0 and therefore the blue border line is not being performed. If I declare count outside the loop I have to declared as final which then line count++ cannot be performed.

Comment: Sorry but no. Anonymous class instance variables don't work that way. Your loop is adding 50 unique listeners each having a unique count starting at 0.